# How can I reduce the size of my file geodatadase?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, arccatalog, compression

We're using file geodatabase for tax mapping. we save building photos and there are 6000 buildings. The size of this data 2GB. So loading the data takes a lot of time we are not unable to do work easily. If there is any options to solve this problem, please share them with me .

Comment: may be compressing and compacting file geaodatabase help you.right click your file geodatabase click compact database .click compress file geodatabase

Comment: what's your rasters format ? Jpg,Tiff,Png ,....

Comment: why don't you use png ? png is good format for storing images . because you can store an image with high quality and low size storage in windows . for example if you store image x in JPEG format and 450 dpi .the image size in windows will be nearly 1.5 megabyte or higher but with PNG format and 450 dpi resolution the size of image will be nearly 250 kb  .

Comment: Yes i made major mistake, picture format . Thanks Mr.Wetland

Comment: your welcome . another way is using raster catalog to save and manage images . right click in the file geodatabase. click raster catalog. load your image in raster catalog and manage them . it's good for georeferenced rasters.

Comment: Are you saving the photos in the file geodatabase, or simply linking to them with an attribute table?  It is not clear from your question which is the case, but makes a significant difference.  Raster data does not compress well, so if it is being stored in the GDB, then it is unlikely to compress, and may potentially be causing performance issues.

Comment: Dear Wetland sir right click in the file geodatabase. click raster catalog. load your image in raster catalog and manage them. (here display Create Arc catalog dialogue box. Is it need to add 6000 photos right. i dont know procedure im doing new this) May i know procedure or steps .

Answer (score 3):

Try to compress database     :

http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Compress%20File%20Geodatabase%20Data%20%28Data%20Management%29

Answer (score 3):

You may even want to consider splitting your geodatabase into two parts, if possible.  One for the tax maps, another for photographs.  However, if your photos are attributes to your tax layer features, then your you should consider [compacting and compressing your file geodatabase](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/File_geodatabases_compressing_vs_compacting/003n0000007r000000/), as already mentioned in the comments.

A couple of notes about compact vs compress.

- You should feel free to [compact your geodatabase](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Compacting_file_and_personal_geodatabases/003n0000007t000000/) at any time, as often as needed.

> Compacting tidies up storage of records in files by reordering them
>   and eliminating empty space. If you frequently add and delete data in
>   a file or personal geodatabase, you should compact your geodatabase on
>   a monthly basis. This can reduce file sizes and improve performance.

- If your data is organized in such a manner that some of it is read-only, then you can consider ["compressing" your data](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Compressing_file_geodatabase_data/003n0000007s000000/).  It should be noted that all features in a compressed state are not editable, read-only.  Therefore if your images are attributes to your tax data, you will not be able to compress the featureclass if you want to continue editing (which I assume you will want to be doing).  Compress is really great for base data that won't change very often.  You can compress the entire geodatabase, a feature dataset, or just the featureclass that contains your images.

> To reduce storage requirements, you can compress vector file
>   geodatabase feature classes and tables (collectively referred to as
>   datasets in the rest of this topic) to a read-only format. Once
>   compressed, display and query performance is comparable to
>   decompressed data. You might find it provides slight performance
>   improvements in some operations but slows slightly in others.